# Хочу сделать логи не получаеться

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот такое сделать хочу (выше)
но у меня только вот так (ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код

```
#If user connect your discord server
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channels = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='「logs」')
    emb = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.green(), title='Присоединился к серверу')
    emb.add_field(name='Кто присоединился', value=member.mention)
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    await channels.send(embed=emb)

#If users disconnect your discord server
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channels = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='「logs」')
    emb = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.red(), title='Покинул сервер')
    emb.add_field(name='Кто ушел', value=member.mention)
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    await channels.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что именно непонятно? Откуда взять `id`, дату регистрации и др. данные? Достаточно разве что, открыть класс [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) в документации и посмотреть как называются соответствующие свойства и методы. Например, дата входа - это `joined_at`, дата регистрации - `created_at`. Если будут более конкретные проблемы, тогда уже стоит задавать вопрос)

Comment: @denisnumb
 можешь помочь написать код пж

Comment: Я и предложил помощь, вы напишите что именно непонятно

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channels = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='「logs」')
    member_create = f'{discord.utils.format_dt(member.created_at, "F")} {discord.utils.format_dt(member.created_at, "R")}'
    embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
                          description=f":inbox_tray: **Участник присоединился к серверу**\n\n"
                                      f"**Участник**\n{member.mention} | `{member.name}#{member.discriminator}`\n\n"
                                      f"**Дата регистрации**\n{member_create}\n")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.display_avatar.url)
    embed.set_footer(text="Member ID: {}".format(member.id), icon_url=member.display_avatar.url)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await channels.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channels = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='「logs」')
    member_join = f'{discord.utils.format_dt(member.joined_at, "F")} {discord.utils.format_dt(member.joined_at, "R")}'
    embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
                          description=f":outbox_tray: **Участник покинул сервер**\n\n"
                                      f"**Участник**\n{member.mention} | `{member.name}#{member.discriminator}`\n\n"
                                      f"**Дата входа**\n{member_join}\n")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.display_avatar.url)
    embed.set_footer(text="Member ID: {}".format(member.id), icon_url=member.display_avatar.url)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await channels.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]